# Yum updates for CentOS by OpenLogic fails on Microsoft Azure

Tags: linux, azure, centos, yum

earlier today I made a fresh install of CentOS in Azure by the provided images by OpenLogic.

When I try to update the system with 'yum update' I get

```
Loaded plugins: 
security http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: 
[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net'" 
Trying other mirror. 
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: 
[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net'" 
Trying other mirror.

..and two more...
```

Setting up Update Process No Packages marked for Update"

Has the hostname changed or is it temporarily unavailable?

Comment: check this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/481501/cpanel-installation-on-azure-centos-gcc-install-fails

Comment: 'yum clean all' doesn't help. The only difference is that I get this message instead: "yum update Loaded plugins: security olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/…: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net'" Trying other mirror. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again"

Comment: The answer on that linked question is more useful than the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Got this answer from OpenLogic:

"Hi Niklas, scheduled Microsoft maintenance was being performed over the weekend and the cloud service was temporarily unavailable. An issue was discovered and fixed that was preventing the redundant service from being started. The URL for yum updates is still http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net."